# Redirect After Login With User Roles

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am trying to redirect a user after login. I want a user employee to be redirected to */home* and user admin to */admin*. Only one user is redirected and the other is shown **401 Unauthorized** and the url is still /login.

```php
if (Auth::user()->authorizeRoles('employee') == true) {
    return '/home';
} else if (Auth::user()->authorizeRoles('manager') == true) {
    return view('admin');
} else {
    return 'login';
}
```

Comment: Use switch case and use return '/admin'; try to use in Middleware

Comment: Change `view('admin')` to `'/admin'`.

Comment: I added `redirect()` for routes..but still retaining **404 Unauthorized**

Comment: you are use standart LoginController or custom ?

Comment: standard loginController